# ReactJS getting state variable from Context returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have array of objects which I am getting from my Context. The problem is, if I am trying to use it, it is undefined. In the code, which I am showcasing, I am mapping over this variable, but I have also tried setting it to new state first. But it had the same result. The only time the code doesn't break is if I use optional chaining. But then it doesn't render mapped content. Can somebody explain my mistake here, as it is not the first time I am seeing it.

P.S. Setting new state to some defined value and then setting it on render to variable from Context doesn't work here.

```
const BacklogDropdown = ({setTask}) => {
    const { tasks } = useContext(UserContext)

    const handleChoose = (e) => {
        const { value } = e.target
        setTask(value)
    }

    return (
        <div className="">
            <p className='text-lg pl-1 font-medium'>Select from Backlog</p>
            <Listbox value={tasks?.backlog} onChange={(e) => handleChoose(e)}>
                <Listbox.Button className='h-10 w-full z-30 bg-background text-lg rounded-md px-2 py-1 border-2 border-grayDark'>{tasks?.backlog[0].name}</Listbox.Button>
                <Listbox.Options className='z-50 h-max w-full'>
                    {tasks?.backlog?.map(task => (
                        <Listbox.Option key={task.id} value={task} className='ui-active:bg-primaryDark ui-active:text-white'>
                            {task.priority}
                            {task.name}
                            <CheckIcon className="hidden ui-selected:block" />
                        </Listbox.Option>
                    ))}
                </Listbox.Options>
            </Listbox>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BacklogDropdown
```

Comment: How did you set up your UserContext? Can you show the code?

Comment: @CuongVu well, that was helpful. Never could I imagine, that I used wrong context. Thanks.